# Building a list of ModelForms based on relation

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I think this is best explained with some simple model code (I'm writing this from scratch so possible syntax issues - unimportant here):

```
class Car(models.Model)
    make = models.CharField(...)
    model = models.CharField(...)

class StatisticType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)

class Statistic(models.Model)
    car = models.ForeignKey('Car')
    stype = models.ForeignKey('StatisticType')
    data = models.CharField(...)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('car', 'stype'),)
```

We have a car with some hard-coded stats and we have some database controlled statistics. I might add `Colours`, `Wheel Size`, etc. The point is it's editable from the admin so neither I or the client need to climb through the data, but it's limited so users can only pick one of each stat (you can't define "Colours" twice).

So I'm trying to write the data input form for this now and I want a list of optional ModelForms that I can chuck on the page. I've got the simplest ModelForm possible:

```
class StatisticForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Statistic
```

The tricky part (in my head) is generating an instance of this ModelForm for each StatisticType, regardless of it existing yet. That is to say if a Car object doesn't have a Colour assigned to it, the form still shows. Similarly, if it does, that instance of a Statistic is loaded in the ModelForm.

#### In my view, how do I generate a list of these things, regardless of there being a pre-existing instance of any given Statistic?

This seems like it should be a stupidly simple thing to do but it's late on Friday and everything looks skwonky.

Comment: An inline modelform factory won't suit your needs?

Comment: @Brandon I've been doing Django for a couple of years and have never heard the phrase "inline modelform factory"! If you think it's the thing (and it does sound suspiciously like it), write it up as an answer with an example based on my example and you win many points!

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say "formset factory", although, it's also not difficult to use a factory pattern to generate form instances.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might want to leverage an [inline model formset factory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets).

That would allow you to create as many instances of your Statistic object as you need. If you're needing to create instances of your StatisticType on the fly, that's a bit different.

When Django instantiates forms, for a foreign key, m2m or choice field, it will only accept choices that it deems "valid", and will complain if you add a choice using JavaScript that doesn't exist in a related model or set of choices server-side.

So, if you need to make StatisticTypes on the fly, and then populate formset instances with this new value, I would suggest using [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com). It's very good at keeping lots of DOM elements in sync when data changes.

Comment: Yeah I wonder if my models are slightly dodgy now - perhaps there should be a m2m in Car to StatisticType that specified Statistic as the "through" class. I'll have a poke on Monday.